# Merging multilinestring into single linestring, keeping the pieces in proper order using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, merge, linestring, dissolve

I have a multilinestring made up of several pieces, some of which are facing the wrong direction.
(Accessible here: http://pastebin.com/89Zcixv5 )

I think what I'm looking for is some utilization of ST_MakeLine, but when I try to use it, the pieces of the trail get put together wrong. (See: http://i5.minus.com/iJ5QVbaA9rm2g.png )

[image]

I have a ton of trails in this format that I need to convert from MultiLineStrings to LineStrings containing the whole trail.

Comment: What format are those LineString points in your pastebin?

Answer (score 5):

Easy, use [ST_LineMerge](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html) with the MultiLineString geometry.

```
SELECT ST_LineMerge(geom) FROM ...
```

Returns a LineString if it is possible, such is the example in the question.

[image: ST_LineMerge]

Answer (score 0):

looking from picture. Valid linestring cannot touch itself. So picture data should could create 3+ linestring.

You can use ST_Dump to dump multi in order which it has been created. Then you can try use st_linemerge until you get multiline. One solution is use st_StartPoint and st_endpoint comparison to linestrings and use st_reverse if needed.(end=end || start=start)

Comment: A code example would be helpful to show how to accomplish this